# Is tungsten gas visible?

Tags: gas-laws, phase, elements

I apologize if this isn't a sufficiently technical question to be posed in this forum.

I'm planning a short story, and unfortunately I've worked in a somewhat sience-y opening. Most of the information I need can be found online, but so far I haven't been able to find any comprehensive information about the properties of some of the less common gases, namely tungsten.

Would pure tungsten gas be visible to the human eye? Does it have any other unique properties that I should know before writing about it?

Comment: You realize that tungsten is a metal, and a pretty heat-resistant one, right? To make it a gas, you have to heat it way above... well, pretty much above _everything_. So yes, it would be glowing hot and thus quite visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily see it: "burn out" the filament of an incandescent lamp from a flashlight (torch) with over-voltage (e.g. put a 1.5 volt lamp across a 12 volt battery). The bluish flash you see is vaporizing tungsten (W), but to the unaided human eye, it looks little different from, say, the "spark" in xenon flash lamps.

Since the filament is *so* hot, it radiates heat rapidly and cools quickly, so is visible only as a flash. If you were to vaporize a few kg of W, it would be visible longer as a blindingly-bright object.

BTW, notice the film on the "dead" lamp: it is condensed W. If the lamp has a vacuum, the film is silvery, but collision with argon or other inert filler makes it rougher, or grayish.